# Is PicketLink supported on all Java EE application servers?

Tags: picketlink

Does PicketLink support all Application Servers?

I'm interested in using it on WebSphere 8.5.5. If not is there an equivalent library for WebSphere security offering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, you can use it in any JEE6+ container. CDI is the only requirement. You can even use Weld SE, for instance.

There are people using it in TomEE and Glassfish too.